# Percentage Pivot on Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm just wondering if Access can get the percentage of sales by person on each day. My table looks like this:

```
Salesman    Sales   Date1
Michael     25      Jan 12
Fred        16      Jan 12
Michael     17      Jan 13
.....
```

I want to get something like this:

```
Salesman     Jan 12    Jan 13
Michael      60.96%    50%
Fred         39.04%    50%
```

I'm only able to get the Number of sales by:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Sales)
SELECT Trouble
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Trouble
PIVOT Date1
```

To get the percentage I tried getting the total using a subquery but i'm getting an error that group functions can't be used in a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to refer to a crosstab query in a subquery, but it is possible to refer to a saved crosstab:

```
SELECT xtab.Salesman, 
       Format([jan 16]/DSum("sales","aa","date1='jan 16'"),"Percent") AS Jan16, 
       Format([Jan 17]/DSum("sales","aa","date1='Jan 17'"),"Percent") AS Jan17
FROM xtab
```

It is a lot easier to build these queries with VBA if they change regularly.